# Setting the theme default/font color in Godot

Tags: godot

Is there a way to set the default/font/fill color for a theme, either in the editor or in the .tres file?

I've found ways to change colors through scripts and by overrides, but I can't find anything on setting a color (besides outline) for a theme. This seems like the most basic thing a theme should do, and I can't find any useful information on it.

By theme I mean the resource type: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_theme.html. The end result should be a default color for text (RichTextLabel) objects by assigning a theme, without having to use theme overrides or scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer elsewhere. There's a little button in the theme toolbar:
[image: a very small nondescript plus sign in the top right corner of the Theme toolbar]

This button adds node types to the theme. Font fill color needs to be set per each component type. In the .tres file the line is (for RichTextLabel):

```
RichTextLabel/colors/default_color = Color( 1, 1, 1, 1 )
```

with each digit representing r, g, b, a on [0,1]

You can style multiple types through inheritance:

```
Control/colors/font_color = Color(1, 0, 0, 1)
```

Most  UI elements use "font_color". RichTextLabel uses "default_color" and Tabs use "font_color_[bg/disabled/fg]".

Comment: Thanks for posting your fix. I was hoping it wasn't this (tedious) but thanks for confirming that it is this.